# Cannot find file name 'cssSelectorHelper'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 2. Recently I followed a youtube tutorial to build a MEAN App from scratch( it is also in github, [enter link description here](https://github.com/bradtraversy/mean_mytasklist)). I then tried integrating it with a bootstrap admin template([enter link description here](https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-2)).

Here comes the problem - while running the bootstrap admin template project itself, there is no problem. Then I copy the admin template "client" folder to the MEAN APP and resolve the dependencies with npm install. Although I have all the dependencies installed, visual studio code is still reporting **[ts] cannot find name '$'** in chart.component.ts (in the above bootstrap admin template link, navigate to /SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-2/src/client/app/dashboard/charts/chart.component.ts) (sorry that i can't post more than 2 links)

> var areaChart: any = **$**('#area-chart');

Cross-referencing back to the original working admin template, the dollarsign "$ "is intepreted as cssSelectorHelper in typescript.

Then i tried to declare the following:

> declare var **$: cssSelectorHelper**;

It then reported that **[ts] Cannot find name 'cssSelectorHelper'**. This made me think that the problem may be due to that cssSelectorHelper is not recognized by typescript.

Anyone can suggest how to resolve this? (I am new to all these. If above explanation does not make sense, please help to clarify as well.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 2 is a framework for `MVC` and `MVVM` pattern while `JQuery` is a little bit of functional. Yes, use can use `JQuery` in Angular 2 but mostly they don't. However, some people some people still find it complicate in writting a directive or a component for every single element.

The problem here is when you import `jquery` in html file using script tag, Angular 2 compiler doesn't know about that. So, you have to somehow, tell the compiler that `jquery` has been imported. Some people just simply include `declare var $: JQueryStatic` or something like that. But the most standard way to do this for `jquery` and other libraries is to intall definitely typed file use typing.

First, you have to install typings https://github.com/typings/typings then search for the library that you want and install its definitely typed file.

Then just include `/// <reference path="path_to_jquery/jquery.d.ts" />` at top of your `.ts` file and everything done! VSCode will support intellisense and all other stuffs for you!

Answer (score 0):

$ in Frontend Development is usually meant for jQuery. You would have to add jQuery as a script-tag and put

```
declare var $: any;
```

at the top of your `.ts` file.

Keep in mind that mixing Angular and jQuery is frowned upon, best practice would be to implement what you are trying to do in Angular 2 itself.

Comment: Hi @Alexander, first of all thanks for taking time to help me out. really appreciated. I have updated my question with more details. I am not sure why the code before integrating, it is running fine. However, when trying to integrate with the MEAN app, I faced the problem. Hope you can help. Thanks